# JsGrid: button to get a value

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, jsgrid

I’m using JsGrid and I can’t find if when I click on a button (inside my JsGrid-each row contains a button) it’s possible: to get a specific value from that row and load it to another page. Something like data editing in another page (maybe just get the ID (for example) and then, in this other page, I do the SELECT again).

If it’s possible (click on a button, get specific value and send it to another page), please let me know which callback to use (and how or an example, just to know how to properly use it).